# Rollup JS build using rollup-plugin-modify plugin not replacing all string instances in the build files (using 'replace-in-file' plugin instead)

Tags: rollupjs

I wanted to tackle file cache updating in a Svelte app and wanted this part of the rollup build. I decide to add a querystring parameter to the file references (such as 'index.html?v=0.1') in the distributed build scripts. I created a constant '`__cVersion__`' in my rollup.config.js script and tried to use the 'rollup-plugin-modify', but that only updated my main.js and App.svelte code (the files being compiled). I also tried the '@rollup/plugin-replace' plugin with the same results. I needed the files I was also copying (not building) from src to public to also to have instances of '`__cVersion__`' replaced in the scripts.

The following was my initial rollup.config.js export function (the string replacement that did not work):

```
export default {
    input: 'src/main.js',
    output: {
        sourcemap: true,
        format: 'iife',
        name: 'app',
        file: 'public/build/bundle.js'
    },
    plugins: [

        // this only seems to work on the main.js and .svelte files
        modify({ 
            '__cVersion__': 'c0.1.19'
         }),

        svelte({
            dev: !production,
            css: css => {
                css.write('public/build/bundle.css');
            }
        }),

        copy({
            targets: [{ 
                src: 'src/bs4.4.1.css', 
                dest: 'public/' 
            },
            { 
                src: 'src/sw.js',
                dest: 'public/' 
            },
            { 
                src: 'src/index.html',
                dest: 'public/' 
            },
            { 
                src: 'src/manifest.json', 
                dest: 'public/' 
            },
            { 
                src: 'src/images/*', 
                dest: 'public/images/'
            }
            ]
        }),

        resolve({
            browser: true,
            dedupe: ['svelte']
        }),
        commonjs(),
        // cache files
        workbox({
            mode: 'injectManifest',
            options: {
                swSrc: 'src/sw.js',
                swDest: 'public/sw.js',
                globDirectory: 'public',
                globPatterns: [
                '**/*.{html,json,js,css,png,map}',
                './manifest.json',
                './images/**',
                './bs4.4.1.css',
                './index.html'
                ]
            }
            }),

        !production && serve(),
        !production && livereload('public'),
        production && terser()

    ],
    watch: {
        clearScreen: false
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

By default, the `rollup-plugin-copy` plugin will trigger on rollup's `buildEnd` hook.
Setting the hook to `writeBundle` fixed this issue for me, like so:

```
copy({
  targets: [
    { 
      src: ..., 
      dest: ... 
    },
    ...
  ],
  hook: "writeBundle",
}),
```

Comment: I had a similar but different issue - this fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to take a different approach since I realized the build process needed to complete before I tried to replace '`__cVersion__`' in the files. After some trial and error I settled on this code:
https://github.com/kuhlaid/svelte2/releases/tag/v0.1.7

If you search the source code for '`__cVersion__`' you will see where I am adding the file revision string to try and force a file cache update...however, that didn't fully fix the issue.

I then looked at the service worker (sw.js) and realized the Workbox 'injectManifest' was actually handling the file revisions. The only problem with my current setup was that I had added '`__cVersion__`' constants to my scripts, but Workbox never saw the replacements since Workbox processed the service worker before I replaced the constants.

What I probably need to do  is copy the src files to a 'staging directory' where I can replace the 'cache' constants in the scripts and then run the build rollup off of the staging files. This 'should' cause Workbox to treat the files as updated and thus assign them different revision numbers in the service worker file. I will try and update this thread when I have that issue worked out.